# TypeError #1007 Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor from array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to make a side scrolling shooter and am generating all enemies with code instead of placement and I keep running into:

> TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.

Relevant Code:

```
tanktimer++;
var n:MovieClip;        
var lv1arr:Array = [24,120,144,264,288,384,408,432,480];                        
var lv1Tarr:Array = ['Tank(1)','Tank(1)','Tank(2)','Tank(1)','Tank(2)','Tank(3)','Tank(1)','Tank(2)','Tank(3)'];

if(tanktimer == lv1arr[we])
{
    trace('work darn you!');
    n = new lv1Tarr[we];
    n.x = 700;
    n.y = 550;
    addChild(n);
    trace('build');
    we++;
}
```

the var 'we' is defined at the top as an Number=0 as is tanktimer.

What I think should be happening is that tanktimer counts up from 0 to 24 and then it will be equal to the first value in lv1arr at which point it will build the first item in lv1Tarr.

I'm pretty sure the problem is:

```
n = new lv1Tarr[we];
```

As the code gets to there then gives the error and generates no tank.  But if I remove lv1Tarr[we] and replace it with Tank(1) it works just fine so clearly Flash doesn't want me using an array in this manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to instantiate a string of `'Tank(1)'`, which is not calling the constructor to `Tank` class.  ActionScript 3 does not `eval()` that to call a function.

This could be achieved by defining an array of functions you wish to call:

```
var lv1Tarr:Array = [
    function():MovieClip {return new Tank(1)},
    function():MovieClip {return new Tank(1)},
    function():MovieClip {return new Tank(2)},
    function():MovieClip {return new Tank(1)},
    function():MovieClip {return new Tank(3)}
    ];
```

You may then call:

```
var n:Tank = new lv1Tarr[we];
```

Or more appropriately:

```
var n:Tank = lv1Tarr[we].call();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make instances of tank and put them in your array then reference them by pulling them from the array (I'm assuming here "we" is within range).  Simply having a Array of Strings and then attempting to call new on them won't work, this is the same as:

new 'Tank(1)'

which is not a valid constructor call

```
tanktimer++;
var n:MovieClip;        
var lv1arr:Array = [24,120,144,264,288,384,408,432,480];                       
var tank1:Tank = new Tank(1);
var tank2:Tank = new Tank(2);
var tank3:Tank = new Tank(3); 
var lv1Tarr:Array = [tank1,tank1,tank2,tank1,tank2,tank3,tank1,tank2,tank3];

if(tanktimer == lv1arr[we])
{
    trace('work darn you!');
    n = lv1Tarr[we]; //<-- this is not a constructor call if you have strings
    n.x = 700;
    n.y = 550;
    addChild(n);
    trace('build');
    we++;
}
```

If instead you want to include the class and constructor arg you could do so like (building on terbooter's answer +1ed):

```
var classesArray:Array = [{clazz:Tank,arg:1}, {clazz:Tank, arg:1}, {clazz:Tank, arg:2}];
for (var i:int=0; i<classesArray.length; i++){
    var clazz:Class =  classesArray[i].clazz as Class;
    var object:Object = new clazz(classesArray[i].arg);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array must contain class objects. But now it contains strings.
Look at quick sample how to instantiate object from class described in array

```
import flash.display.Sprite;

var classesArray:Array = [Sprite, Sprite, MovieClip];
for (var i:int=0; i<classesArray.length; i++){
    var clazz:Class =  classesArray[i] as Class;
    var object:Object = new clazz();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem (I believe) is that `we` is not limited to the length of `lv1Tarr`, so eventually `lv1Tarr[we]` evaluates to `null`.

This is why you have no problem when you use `Tank(1)` instead.

Try incrementing `we` like this:

```
++we;
we %= lv1arr.length();
```

That way, `we` does not exceed the length of the array.